# Grant permissions error on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new my MySQL admin from the command line and typically use Phpmyadmin or MySql workbench to admin machines.  I'm getting a problem while trying to grant a user access to DBs and hoping I could get some help to figure it out.

```
    [root@server20039]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 21
Server version: 5.5.29 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'maintenance'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'qwerty' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Then I tried this and still got the same error

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'qwerty' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'qwerty'  
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I could really use a hand figuring this out!

Comment: [Don't try giving a user access to everything.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check user:

```
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Check privileges:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*03465AB87C2B44D98228458669A91479C2BAAA6C' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you have recently updated MySQL run: `mysql_upgrade` and then restart MySQL daemon.

Comment: mysql> SHOW GRANTS;

| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABL                                                                                ES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO                                                                                 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*02C4C7B76AEA81A9120FFC80F2933A99F0AE3499' WITH GRANT OPTION